# Como Agrupar Registros en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, tablas

Buen día.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con esto, resulta que estoy trabajando en sql server con la siguiente consulta:

```
select distinct ClaveProdServ, 
                   Descripcion,  
                   COUNT(Descripcion)as Cantidad, 
                   AVG(ValorUnitario)as ValorUnitarioCFDI, 
                   SUM(ValorUnitario)as SubTotal, 
                   ImporteIvaUnitario, 
                   SUM(ImporteIvaUnitario)as ivaTotal,
                   (select SUM(ValorUnitario) + SUM(ImporteIvaUnitario)) as total,
                   select SUM(ValorUnitario) + SUM(ImporteIvaUnitario) / (select SUM(Cantidad)))as ValorUnitario
                          from Tbl_ConceptosCfdiInventarioInicial
group by ClaveProdServ, Descripcion, ValorUnitario, ImporteIvaUnitario, Cantidad
```

lo que me trae como resultado lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito todos esos datos, solo que al agruparlos, hace la distinción de la columna ValorUnitarioCFDI por lo que si el precio tiene variación genera otra fila con la misma descripción, lo que quiero lograr es agrupar por descripción luego sumar el valor unitario, sumarle el ivaTotal para después dividir entre la cantidad de productos por descripción y tener un valor unitario, tampoco logro el resultado correcto para el ValorUnitario.
de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya logré resolver lo del valor unitario, solo queda agrupar por descripción sin tener en cuenta si hay diferencias en alguna otra columna

Comment: Entiendo que sería esto: `group by ClaveProdServ, Descripcion`

Comment: Patricio Moracho, me marca error si solo agrupo por los dos campos que dices, me dice que la columna ImporteIvaUnitario no es válida porque no se encuentra contenida en ninguna función ni en la clausula group by

Comment: Perdón, agregala también al  `Group by`

Comment: por un lado tienes un `count(x) as cantidad` y luego un `sum(cantidad)`. ¿Cada fila representa un producto (sin cantidad) o una cantidad X de productos y por tanto tiene una columna llamada `cantidad`?

Comment: jachguate , ya hice algunas correcciones, la tabla tiene una columna Cantidad, en mi query donde tengo COUNT(Descripcion)as Cantidad, lo cambie por un SUM(Cantidad)as Cantidad

Comment: Lo sigo viendo igual, quizás no le diste guardar a la edición de la pregunta. Utiliza la notación @Erikc para que me llegue una notificación al escribir tu comentario, de otra forma no me entero de tu respuesta.